# Strange spacing issue in IE 7

Tags: html, css, doctype

I have strange spacing issue occurring between servers.

I use IE 8 and FF 7.0.1
Everything looks fine in FF in all 3 environments

For IE 8:
Everything looks fine on my local machine (running IIS 7)
Everything looks fine on my build server (running IIS 7)
The spacing occurs on my staging server (running IIS 6)

In my web.config I've set the following code:

```
<httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
          <clear />
          <add name="X-UA-Compatible" value="IE=8" />
      </customHeaders>
  </httpProtocol>
```

That seems to work on IIS 7 but is unsupported for IIS 6. Because I'm not a server admin, I've been trying to determine what I can fix on the code-side and it's led me to the css I'm using.

```
        <header>
        <img src="@Url.Content("~/Images/header_my_logo.png")" alt="my_logo" id="my_logo" />
        <img src="@Url.Content("~/Images/my_button.jpg")" alt="my_logo2" id="my_logo2" width="160" height="57" />
        <nav>
            <ul id="menu">
                <li class="aHome">
                    @Html.ActionLink("Goals", "Index", "Home")</li>
                <li class="blank">
                    @Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
```

On the CSS end:

```
#my_logo, #my_logo2
{ 
float:right; 
/*--- margin: 5px 15px 15px 15px; ---*/
margin: 5px 15px 0px 15px;
}
```

and

```
ul#menu 
{
border-bottom: 1px solid #51759B;
width: 563px;
padding: 2px 0;
position: relative;
margin: 45px 0 0;
text-align: left;
}

ul#menu li {
display: inline;
list-style: none;
}

ul#menu li a, ul#menu li a:hover {
padding: 15px 30px;
font-size: 14px;
font-weight: bold;
text-decoration: none;
color: #51759b;
border-radius: 0 0 0 0;
-webkit-border-radius: 0 0 0 0;
-moz-border-radius: 0 0 0 0;
}

ul#menu li a
{
-moz-background-size: 100px 35px;
background-size: 100px 35px;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-origin:border-box;
text-decoration: none;
}

.aHome a {
background-image: url(/ILP/Images/nav_hometab.png);
color:#fff !important;
}
```

My logos appear side-by-side in the upper-right corner. The navigation (tabs) appear below those. It's between the logos and the tabs where I'm seeing spacing (and also a slight issue with line height in-general for my tabs as the top is shaved off).  I will try to get an image posted shortly.

I really appreciate any help!

Comment: Of note - I'm playing with dev tools in IE and it really seems the UL#menu is where the problem seems to be. I could be wrong... but that's where my suspicion lies. Also, if I remove the "width" attribute then adjust my "margin" values it works... but breaks Firefox

Comment: where is the odd spacing occurring?

Comment: Good question - sorry!  My logos appear side-by-side in the upper-right corner. The navigation (tabs) appear below those.  It's between the logos and the tabs where I'm seeing spacing.

Comment: I notice you're using `<header>` and `<nav>` HTML5 elements... IE8 and earlier doesn't support these properly, which can cause layout problems if you use them. There are hacks such as HTML5Shiv and Modernizr which will fix this; are you using them?

Comment: Hi - I wasn't aware of that - but I am using Modernizr. I removed it earlier on and noticed all kinds of crazy stuff happening so I put it back :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `<add name="X-UA-Compatible" value="IE=8" />` works to fix it on IIS7, and you're looking for a fix you can add to your HTML, look no further than:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8">
```

Add it to your `<head>`.

Though, it would be better to completely get rid of `X-UA-Compatible` (or set it to `IE=edge`, which means "use the newest available version"), and fix your site to work in all versions of Internet Explorer. Forcing IE9 and newer to display as IE8 is not a good thing.

Comment: You should also be able to add a custom header in IIS6: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725672.aspx

Comment: @thirtydot The meta tag only seems to work on IIS7 and not IIS6. You're correct about the browser stuff - and it's why I'm looking at the code. However, I didn't mention this is an internal app where I know we all use IE8.

Comment: The web server version can't affect whether the `meta` tag works. See for yourself: http://hsivonen.iki.fi/doctype/#ie8modes

Comment: Thanks - I'll need to have it migrated to the server to test then. I really appreciate the help and will update as to the results!

Comment: The file has been uploaded to our IIS6 server and I can confirm this fixed the issue.  I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be the infamous IE whitespace bug rearing it's ugly head. Try putting the entire menu code on one line and see if that fixes it. e.g.

```
<ul id="menu"><li class="aHome">@Html.ActionLink("Goals", "Index", "Home")</li><li class="blank">@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li></ul>
```

Comment: Hrm -that may have done it... it didn't work at first (cache, I suspect) but I just tried IE's inprivate and it worked!  I will clear cache and accept if all is well. Thank so much!

Comment: Unfortunately it seems inprivate defaulted to document mode of IE8 standards. When I switch it back to IE7 standards the spacing remains. Any more ideas?  I appreciate the help

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the `img` logos to `display:block` or adding `vertical-align:top` ?

Comment: Thanks - I had tried those but never at the same time. Unfortunately the spacing still remains.